# How to open webview window with particular url for MacOS using Swift

Tags: swift, xcode, macos

I have been trying to get **webview with url(www.google.com)** with various code  but has no luck, also there is problem *I'm face linking my webview with the view controller on the storyboard* so will share the code so please help me out with this task.

```
import Cocoa
import WebKit

class ViewController: NSViewController {

    @IBOutlet weak var webView: WebView!

    //let webViewController = WebViewController()


    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        //let url = "http:www.google.com"
        //self.webView.mainFrame.loadRequest(NSURLRequest(URL: NSURL(string: url)! as URL))

        let url = NSURL (string: "http://www.google.com")

        let requestObj = NSURLRequest(url: url! as URL)

        webView.mainFrame.load(requestObj as URLRequest)

        /*
        //Open in browser
        if let url = URL(string: "https://www.google.com"), NSWorkspace.shared().open(url) {
            print("default browser was successfully opened")
        }
        */

    }

    override var representedObject: Any? {
        didSet {
            // Update the view, if already loaded.
        }
    }

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to set PolicyDelegate and override the method delegates.

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        webView.policyDelegate = self

        webView.mainFrame.loadRequest(NSURLRequest(URL: YOUR_URL_OBJECT))

    }
```

Delegate methods

> webView:decidePolicyForNewWindowAction:request:newFrameName:decisionListener:
>   webView:decidePolicyForNavigationAction:request:frame:decisionListener: